# ASUS Chromebook internal keyboard not working on Kali Linux 4.18

Tags: linux, keyboard

I have an ASUS Chromebook (C202SA-GJ0027), running Kali Linux.

At boot time, the internal keyboard works perfectly well. At the GRUB menu the internal keyboard works perfectly well.

If I boot into Linux `4.17.0-kali3-amd64`, the internal keyboard works perfectly well.

If I boot into Linux `4.18.0-kali2-amd64`, the internal keyboard is completely unresponsive, apart from the power button. An external USB keyboard works perfectly.

On 4.17, evemu-describe gives me:

```
/dev/input/event0: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event1: Lid Switch
# etc.
```

On 4.18, no keyboard:

```
/dev/input/event0: Lid Switch
# etc. as on 4.17 but shifted down for missing keyboard
```

So, it looks like the internal keyboard isn't found at all

`diff`ing `dmesg` outputs between kernels looks broadly similar (apart from addresses/sizes/versions) except notably (`-` is 4.17, `+` is 4.18):

```
-acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
+acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
```

and later:

```
-serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 182
+i8042: probe of i8042 failed with error -22
```

shortly after which:

```
-input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
```

Comment: You might start by comparing `dmesg` output from booting the two kernels and seeing if anything jumps out? (If you're comfortable building your own kernels, you could try bisecting between the two versions, but I'm sure you've thought of that.)

Comment: Ah, thank you - dmesg was indeed useful, will update! I figure bisecting is an option but it's not something I'm especially comfortable with and this box is quite space-constrained which will make it even more tedious...

Comment: `-22` is `-EINVAL` but that's not much more to go on!

Comment: I wonder if some other change is causing the keyboard to switch into a different mode to communicate with the host system, that's supported by the CrOS kernel configuration but not Kali's? I think i8042 is Ye Olde PC Keyboard.

Comment: It doesn't help that everything I find on Google/SO talks about xinput, and this isn't just an X issue!